# Common element in list of strings up to some point

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in Python:

```
['movie-about-trees', 'movie-about-birds', 'movie-about-grass']
```

I'm trying to get the common elements (characters) of these items BUT in an ordered way up to the point where they become different.

So the output should ideally be:

```
movies-about-
```

---

This example should have no match:

```
['bird-movie', 'movie-about-birds', 'movie-about-grass']
```

---

And this:

```
['movie-on-trees', 'movie-about-birds', 'movie-theaters']
```

should give:

```
movie-
```

---

Comment: What did you try up to now? [ask]

Comment: Yes, sorry, submitted it before I had to chance to show what I've already done.

Basically: looping over each character from the first entry and comparing it with all others in the list, but it seemed inefficient.

Comment: @vaultah that seems like the solution!